# when importing project from eclipse to intelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I have a multi-module project in Eclipse, which works fine.

Now I want to work with IntelliJ (I have 12.1), so I imported project to IntelliJ, and have configured below things in it:

- All modules
- configured all lib (.jar) files with each project where I need (by adding lib)
- have configured module dependencies
- have configured tomcat7 with them, and added it in dependency of module too

Everything looks OK, but when I run the project it shows:

> `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xx/yyy/zzzz`

Although `org.xx.yyy.zzzz` class exist in `model` module, which is already added to `web` module (my project has 2 modules `web` and `model`), and also scope of dependency is set to `provided`.

What should I try to resolve this problem?  Help me if I am missing something.

Comment: `Provided` might be the wrong scope in this case, try `Compile`.

Comment: No @CrazyCoder, because this model lib should be available at run time too. so I think `provided` is right scope. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.

I kept the scope to `provided`, and Added model module to artifacts and it worked. :)